# SQL - Sum of NAs

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, pivot

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFufY.png)I am working with the Olympics data (https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results). I tried to get the sum of NAs for some columns using SQLite. The sum of NAs of the columns is showing 0 (zero).[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSape.png) The code is below, please help. Thanks

```
SELECT
  Sex,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ('Age' = 'NA') THEN (1.0) ELSE (0.0) END) AS NA_age,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ('Height' = 'NA') THEN (1.0) ELSE (0.0) END) AS NA_height,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ('Weight' = 'NA') THEN (1.0) ELSE (0.0) END) AS NA_weight,
  COUNT(*)
FROM olymp
GROUP BY Sex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use single quotes around the column names.
Single quotes are used for string literals.
Change to this:

```
SELECT
  Sex,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (Age = 'NA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA_age,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (Height = 'NA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA_height,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (Weight = 'NA') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA_weight,
  COUNT(*)
FROM olymp
GROUP BY Sex
```

But in SQLite there is no need for `CASE` expressions.
Use the boolean expressions inside `SUM()`:

```
SELECT
  Sex,
  SUM(Age = 'NA') AS NA_age,
  SUM(Height = 'NA') AS NA_height,
  SUM(Weight = 'NA') AS NA_weight,
  COUNT(*)
FROM olymp
GROUP BY Sex
```

Comment: Thanks forpas, but I am still getting the same 0 (zero) outputs for these columns using the two codes you suggested. What could be wrong?

Comment: Post a sample data of your data.

Comment: @IntrepidNutrepidation maybe you mean `Age is null` instead of `Age = 'NA'`?

Comment: ID     Name   Sex     Age Height Weight Team  NOC   Games  Year Season City 
<dbl>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>
  9967 Pave~   M        28    172     70      Czec~ TCH   1992~  1992 Winter Albe~
 111428 Helg~  F        20    171     61      Arge~ ARG   1968~  1968 Winter Gren~
 127942 Paul~  M        29     NA    109   Germ~ GER   1936~  1936 Summer Berl~
  37121 Juli~   M        18     NA     NA    Germ~ GER   1900~  1900 Summer Paris

Comment: @GMB, The missing values are not null. I load the excel file in R studio and using the sqlite

Comment: @IntrepidNutrepidation: in that case, the above query should do what you want.

Comment: @forpas, GMB the sample data is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFufY.png

Comment: @IntrepidNutrepidation try with `SUM(TRIM(Age) = 'NA')` just in case there are spaces in the columns.

Comment: See a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=19e22edf68fc24d1d8840222016ba2ae

Comment: @forpas from the screenshot you gave, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=19e22edf68fc24d1d8840222016ba2ae - when the datatype is integer (Age) sum of NA is not displayed but when it's text (Height and Weight) the sum is seen. The datatype of the original excel file ((https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results) for these 3 columns is `REAL`. I used CAST() to change datatype still got 0. I also used the TRIM() but still 0 outputs

Comment: The data type of the columns is irrelevant. Since there are values like 'NA' in a column then it is considered and should be defined as TEXT. The code works fine with SQLite. Are you sure that you are using SQLite? Which tool do you use to run the queries?

Comment: I used R studio - RSQLite

Comment: I have never used it so I can't say if it is suitable for use with SQLite databases. Also as you can see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f2bf1f967b8bc8535ea73685cfd90687 even if the data types of the columns is INTEGER the results are correct.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will load the data into Spark or Jupyter notebook and see how it goes. I will keep you posted

Comment: You can use DB Browser for SQLite: https://sqlitebrowser.org

Comment: @forpas I was able to execute the code successfully with DB Browser. Thanks